# Android authentication

Tags: json, authentication, rest-api, android

I'm using WordPress REST API (Version 2), and I want to authenticate Android native app with my self-hosted WordPress site.
How can I perform that using username and password ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to authenticate an app with the REST API would be to use OAuth. There's a [good section](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/#oauth-authentication)  on OAuth Authentication the REST API documentation site. You will need to install the [OAuth1 plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1) on your site as well.

There are some gotchas with implementing the OAuth plugin on WordPress. I found [this article on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/oauth-fun-oauth1/) captured some of the complexity of setting it up.

You'll need an OAuth library in your Android application as well, I've seen [ScribeJava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) recommended more than once. In fact, here's a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821628/how-to-call-oauth-1-0-api-in-android) with a good implementation example.

If your app is just in testing mode, you could use [Basic Authentication](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/#application-passwords-or-basic-authentication) instead of OAuth, because it's easier to implement, but it's not recommended for production use because it's less secure.

Comment: Can we authenticate directly with username & password from our app or we have to redirect users to site for authentification and then redirect them to the app.